# Is the real spinor representation of the Lorentz group irreducible?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors, majorana-fermions

Specifically the $(\frac{1}{2},0)\oplus(0,\frac{1}{2})$ representation. Given that we label representations by the corresponding representations of the complexified Lie group, the direct sum can be misleading when we focus strictly on the real representation of the group. For example, the real adjoint representation cannot be reducible despite often being written as $(1,0)\oplus(0,1)$. Is the real representation reducible, or irreducible?

Comment: A Dirac spinor in 3+1D can be decomposed into two Majorana spinors, if that's the question.

Comment: Indeed, the adjoint representation of the Lorentz group  is irreducible.

Comment: @CosmasZachos and does the same go for real representations of the spinor rep?

Comment: Spinors are reducible, into two Weyl, or two Majoranas.

Comment: My question was ill posed. One cannot ask about a representation without specifying the vector space one intends the group to act on. Majorana spinors transform under an irreducible representation of the Lorentz group when the vector space is taken to be $\mathbb{R}^4$, but under a reducible representation when the underlying vector space is taken to be $\mathbb{C}^4$.